# Hadoop YARN authentication: Mismatched URI: default/; expecting: null/default

Tags: spring, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, spring-cloud

**Issue**

I'm trying to deploy an Hadoop YARN application with Spring Boot, following this tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2014/02/06/spring-yarn-application-model

When I do so, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(javax.security.sasl.SaslException): DIGEST-MD5: digest response format violation. Mismatched URI: default/; expecting: null/default
```

The full logs are available here: http://pastebin.com/CkADMWDL

**What I tried**

I tried adding changing the default java SASL realm, adding the following code in the client, the container, and the appmaster, but without succes:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.security.sasl.digest.realm", "null/default");
```

Also, I tried to change my Java Hadoop dependencies to 2.7.0 (my Yarn version), because I noticed they were either 2.6.0 or 2.7.1 on the Spring releases. That didn't work either.

**Questions**

How could I fix this problem ? Is there another property I should set ?

**More details**

Maybe those detail can help solve the problem.

What I'm doing is launching my client application on my computer. This application is configured with the real YARN hostname, and actually deploys the appmaster to YARN with success. The logs I provided are the appmaster's, on the YARN cluster, when it attempts to deploy it related container.

Also note that I had to manually deploy the appmaster jar to the HDFS, otherwise YARN doesn't find it. It is deployed in the `/data/mapr.my-domain.com/java/` folder, which is actually an NFS mount on the HDFS. The `java` folder is actually a folder at the HDFS root.